# How to deploy apps to cloud run using buildpack as cloudbuild trigger configuration?

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, buildpack

I'm trying to deploy python apps on cloud run & i want to use buildpacks as cloud build trigger configuration. I created  cloud build trigger and when i run it the image was created succesfully on container registry, but the service on cloud run still wasn't created.

I've tried to add cloudbuild.yaml to create cloud run service but still not helping. Can anybody give some advice?

Comment: Is your container valid? Did you try to start it?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you ever figure anything out?

Comment: @csf Nope, I ended up deploying my app by creating a cloud run service first, as in this  video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nf3KAY-i6zw

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Buildpacks would build, but not deploy.
I ended up creating a cloudbuild.yaml with Buildpacks as the first step, then deploy with gcloud as the second step. You still get the convenience of the buildpacks, but it takes a few more steps.
Example:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/pack"
    id: "BUILD and PUSH with cloudpacks"
    entrypoint: "pack"
    args:
      [
        "build",
        "--builder=gcr.io/buildpacks/builder",
        "--publish",
        "gcr.io/<project>/<path-to-image>:$COMMIT_SHA",
      ]
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    id: "DEPLOY to cloud run"
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
      [
        "run",
        "deploy",
        "<name of service>",
        "--image",
        "gcr.io/<project>/<path-to-image>:$COMMIT_SHA",
        "--region",
        "<region>",
      ]
```